# Add a nonstandard marker property

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

To allow users to delete the correct marker among those on the map, I need to associate each marker with its datastore ID, which is a string. I had originally thought I could set the ID as an integer and use the existing `zIndex` property of markers. That lead to the code below for creating each physical marker. (But, alas, I was unable to access the integer ID value.)

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point, map: map , title: text, icon: icon,  zIndex: ID});
```

I don't know how to add a property to the prototype of `google.maps.Marker` that would hold the ID string, and I imagine it is not advisable to alter such prototypes, anyway. So how is this done? Do I have to use the `zIndex` property as an index for an array that contains the actual ID's as elements which correspond to the `zIndex` value? That's awkward, too. Surely there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You can set for example `marker.id = ID` and access it later.

Comment: Your comment basically answers my question. But I am still stuck because I don't know which clicked marker to hide. I know which marker to delete from my google-app-engine datastore, because that is the value of `marker.id`. I'll have to ask another question, about the hiding, because even @jonathanwilson's answer does not associate the clicked marker with the the one to hide, I don't think, because `hideMarkersWithIdIn()` requires indexes not marker clicks as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of `locations`:

```
var markers = [];
for(var i in locations){
    var loc = locations[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc.point
        map: map,
        title: loc.text,
        icon: loc.icon
    });
    marker.id = loc.id;
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

You can do this because each marker is just a plain old javascript object.

Then you can define a function to hide markers with particular IDs:

```
function hideMarkersWithIdIn(ids){
    var markersToRemove = markers.filter(function(marker){
        return ids.indexOf(marker.id) > -1;
    });
    markersToRemove.forEach(function(marker){
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
}
```

That can be used like

```
hideMarkersWithIdIn([1,5,3])
```